# Skype channel not working, others do

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, skype-bots

I'm trying to get started with the botframework and I managed to get my bot to work on 2 channels so far, but when I try to add skype it does not respond.

I have tested it on kik and webchat, both works smoothly and fast but when I try to add a skype channel and message the bot, nothing happens, I don't even get the post request on my endpoint.

When I try to send it a message on skype I get this little yellow triangle near it: [image: Skype yellow triangle]

Is there something I need to do to make the skype channel work? 
I tried removing the channel and adding it again, same results